# jQuery add class on mouseenter and remove it 500ms after mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, mouseover, addclass

I have a small menu, wanna add the class to submenu items when hovering around. Check the code you will understand:

**The HTML**

```
<ul class="root">
  <li>Menu1
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li>Menu11</li>
    <li>Menu12</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu2
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li>Menu21</li>
    <li>Menu22</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**The JS**

```
$('.root li').mouseenter( function( e1 ) {
    var thisItem = $(this);

    setTimeout( function( e1 ) {

        if ( $(thisItem).children().hasClass('open') ) { 
            return; 
        } else {
            $(thisItem).children().addClass('open');
            $(thisItem).siblings().children().removeClass('open');
        } 

    }, 200 );

}).mouseleave( function( e2 ) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    setTimeout( function( e2 ) {
        if ( !$(thisItem).children().hasClass('open') ) { return; } else {                                  
            $(thisItem).children().removeClass('open'); 
        }
    }, 500 );
});
```

**Some CSS**

```
.root li { display: inline-block; background: #eee; color: #333 }   
.root li:hover { background: #333; color: #fff }    
.submenu li { clear: both }

.root li ul {display: none}
.root li ul.open {display: block}
```

**The problem**

When mouse out of the menu12 or menu22 and mouse back in, during the 500ms timeout after mouse out, the submenu will bubble ugly and eventually will close.

**The Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/5G3BH/12/

**Thanks for any reply**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the set timer on mouseenter and mouseleave

```
$('.root li').mouseenter(function (e1) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    clearTimeout(thisItem.data('hoverTimer'))
    var timer = setTimeout(function (e1) {

        if ($(thisItem).children().hasClass('open')) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(thisItem).children().addClass('open');
            $(thisItem).siblings().children().removeClass('open');
        }

    }, 200);
    thisItem.data('hoverTimer', timer)
}).mouseleave(function (e2) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    clearTimeout(thisItem.data('hoverTimer'))
    var timer = setTimeout(function (e2) {
        if (!$(thisItem).children().hasClass('open')) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(thisItem).children().removeClass('open');
        }
    }, 500);
    thisItem.data('hoverTimer', timer)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nqQHM/)

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5G3BH/16/)

Used [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout) to clear the `setTimeout`

```
$('.root li').mouseenter(function (e1) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    clearTimeout(x);

    y = setTimeout(function (e1) {

        if ($(thisItem).children().hasClass('open')) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(thisItem).children().addClass('open');
            $(thisItem).siblings().children().removeClass('open');
        }

    }, 200);

}).mouseleave(function (e2) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    clearTimeout(y);
    x = setTimeout(function (e2) {
        if (!$(thisItem).children().hasClass('open')) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(thisItem).children().removeClass('open');
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: @Danny i was the 1st to answer check time

Comment: Thanks man but this one didn't work, sorry. The answer I marked worked on first click.

Comment: Yes now your demo works too. I seem to have issues with my FF, didn't work when I checked first. I marked the other one because looks more clean to me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the timeouts so that they don't fire.
http://jsfiddle.net/5G3BH/14/

```
var timeoutHandler;
    $('.root li').mouseenter( function( e1 ) {
        var thisItem = $(this);
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);    
        timeoutHandler = setTimeout( function( e1 ) {

            if ( $(thisItem).children().hasClass('open') ) { 
                return; 
            } else {
                $(thisItem).children().addClass('open');
                $(thisItem).siblings().children().removeClass('open');
            } 

        }, 200 );

    }).mouseleave( function( e2 ) {
        var thisItem = $(this);
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
        timeoutHandler = setTimeout( function( e2 ) {
            if ( !$(thisItem).children().hasClass('open') ) { return; } else {                                  
                $(thisItem).children().removeClass('open'); 
            }
        }, 500 );
    });
```